# asp.net SQL SUM clause with join on another table syntax error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I am developing a gridview fill on asp.net web forms and thought the SQL statement would have similar syntax compared to mysql.

I have a CustomerList and CustomerTracking table where CustomerTracking has a CustUUID that links to the CustomerList table entries. I am also trying to get the SUM of all entries that match the CustUUID from banner in CustomerTracking

Here is the sql statement I am trying to parse.

```
string command2 = "SELECT b.Name, b.Link, SUM(t.CustomerTracking) as CustomerTrackingList, SUM(t.ClickCount) as ClickCount " +
                    "FROM CustomerList as b JOIN CustomerTracking as t" +
                    "IN b.CustUUID= t.CustUUID" +
                    "WHERE t.date> 11/21/2006";
```

Have also tried explicitly stating the table names as follows.

```
string command2 = "SELECT CustomerList.Name, CustomerList.Link, SUM(CustomerTrackingList.CustomerTracking) CustomerTracking, SUM(CustomerTrackingList.ClickCount) ClickCount " +
                    "FROM CustomerList JOIN CustomerTrackingList" +
                    "ON CustomerList.CustUUID = CustomerTracking.CustUUID" +
                    "WHERE CustomerTracking.date> 11/21/2006";
```

I keep getting sytax errors when I try and invoke sda.fill(dt) in the code behind file below. Is the syntax correct or am I missing some decorators that asp.net is looking for?
This is the error Visual Studio is showing me!

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '.'.'
```

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command2))
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
        {
           sda.Fill(dt);
           GridView2.DataSource = dt;
           GridView2.DataBind();
                            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have also tried ON clause on after the FROM line as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even provide the error, however I can immediately see your date is not quoted, it should be

```
WHERE t.CreateDate > '11/21/2006'
```

and I would suggest always to use ISO dates eg '20061121'

And if you actually build your string you will be sending this to SQLServer

```
SELECT b.Name, b.Link, SUM(t.ImpressionCount) as ImpressionCount, SUM(t.ClickCount) as ClickCount FROM Banner as b JOIN BannerTracking as **tIN** b.BannerId = **t.BannerIdWHERE** t.CreateDate > 11/21/2006
```

Added -

Make sure you add white space at the end of each section to ensure it gets parsed correctly.

Comment: added the error the IDE was throwing. It does not give alot of insights. I will try out your solution.

Comment: Also noticed in your first statment you have IN instead of ON

Comment: ```System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '.'.'``` same error as before

Comment: tried ON and IN. did not change the error output unfortunately

Comment: Then it's time to  rule out the query itself or how you're invoking it, can you run the statement in SSMS?

Comment: works in MySqlWorkbench, will have to look into SSMS. While I download that and set it up, I will try to execute the query directly on the database through Visual Studio IDE itself.

Comment: 100+ upvotes to the above comment - you HAVE to try this in SSMS. Put a debug.print in your code - spit out the sql and then cut + paste what that actual string is into SSMS. This is like shooting darts in the dark. You have errors in the sql, and EVEN have errors in the string concatenations. You have " AS t" + "IN b....." and that will become " AS tIN B". So spaces missing between the lines you are cobbling together. And if this is MySQL, then AGAIN take the actual string in code from the debug.print command and try that in workbench. I see spaces missing etc.

Comment: Ok so ignore SSMS, you didn't tag your RDBMS and I made an assumption it was sql server because of asp.net

Comment: No it is SQL server not mysql, I was testing the command with dummy data to see if it worked as needed. I will still try with SSMS. Since I thought the syntax shouldn't be too different

Comment: now I'm confused, MySqlworkbench is... MySql. Just try it not as concatenated in .net lol

Comment: yeah I will remove all concats. I was trying on mysqlworkbench since that was the one I had installed and was a little bit more convenient. Now that I know SSMS exists, I will use that. Will update my question with clear error outputs if I don't end up figuring it out. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Reading sql as part of multiple quoted strings is hard, even for something this small. Add spaces at the end of each line, on two of your lines they'll be concatenated into meanliess junk. And you still need the date quoted... ;-)

Comment: It was the concatenation, now I am getting ```System.Web.HttpException: 'A field or property with the name 'ImpressionCount' was not found on the selected data source.'```

Comment: can you add a edit to the answer to suggest the concat issue. I will accept it. What a stupid mistake on my part without adding a space at the end. SQL works though!